# How to represent this in the Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, tensorflow2.0

```
object_for_each_prior[prior_for_each_object] = torch.LongTensor(range(n_objects)).to(device)

object_for_each_prior-> tensor([0, 0, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0], device='cuda:0') 8732
prior_for_each_object.-> tensor([8709], device='cuda:0')
```

I'm not sure what does object_for_each_prior[prior_for_each_object]  mean in torch 
but I want to know how to represent this in Tensorflow?

Comment: It just doing indexing and then assignment operation. It will set value at `prior_for_each_object` position or index in `object_for_each_prior` tensor.

Comment: ok thank you , then how to write torch.LongTensor(range(n_objects)).to(device) in tensorflow?

Comment: I am not sure how to do it in `Tensorflow` I was just explaining what it means in `PyTorch` as you had mention what that means in torch so.